# Email succesfully sent but not appear in Sent Items (Microsoft 365)

Tags: email, outlook, office365

Hi Good day to everyone here.

My first questions, here we go but i'll try to explain it the best way I could.

I develop auto sending email features using javaxmail in my application for my customer.
Previously when using setting smtp.office365.com I able to send email and the copies of sent email are display in Sent Items folder.

Recently when there are hiccup with smtp office (time out frequently), the IT department at my customer change the setting to use local server instead for smtp (with ip address 172.162.etc.etc). However since the start using this new setting, the email no longer appear in Sent Items but the email still able to sent out ( I test sending email to myself and able to received it ).

Since Im not really familiar and have very limited knowledge on server side for mail server, is there anything I can suggest to the IT department to check for? I only can login the email account on web (https://outlook.office.com/mail/) but when using outlook it required authentication. With web mail i already go thru all settings available and didn't see anything related.

Thanks in advance. Sorry if the question confusing and misleading.

Comment: What code do you use for sending emails? Could you be more specific?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev The code are exactly as in the tutorial here. [link](https://netcorecloud.com/tutorials/send-email-in-java-using-gmail-smtp/) 

However for the config part, below is the code;
         Properties properties = System.getProperties();

         properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
         properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
         properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "172.16.17.90");
         properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
         properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");

Comment: @AhmadRaimiJasmi - any code belongs in your question, properly-formatted, and not in comments. It's very difficult to read unformatted code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course - your local SMTP server knows absolutely nothing about your remote Exchange mailbox. It cannot possibly place anything in your Sent Items folder.

You need to send using your Exchange Server - its SMTP server does place sent messages in the Sent Items folder owned by the authenticated user. Keep in mind that MS has recently disabled basic auth in M365. You need to re-enable it for your tenant and the particular mailbox used to send messages.

Comment: Hi @Dmitry, so it seem nothing can be done? How about something i found while looking around googling saying about save sent item? is that even available or possible for local smtp?

Comment: No, You either send through M365 SMTP server or you create a fake item in the Sent Items folder yourself.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again, what it mean by creating a fake item in Sent Items?

Comment: I mean creating an item in the Sent Items folder that looks like a message sent by Outlook. Fairly tricky if you are using Outlook Object Model alone, but easy with Redemption.

Answer (score 0):

Using another SMTP server other than Exchange Online's (while authenticating using the corresponding user account) won't allow the item to appear in Sent Items.

An alternative you have is to send the item to the mailbox in Cc or Bcc and optionally set up a Rule in Exchange to subsequently move the corresponding items to Sent Items (or another folder) in that mailbox.